# how do i find the greatest length from a given point and make the program stop after that point with the greatest length hits the middle?

Tags: python, pygame

My program makes 30 randomly generated points that spawn from the edge of the map that move towards the center.
My program works fine, but how would I find the largest length of these points and then say "if the largest length hits the middle, reset?

I just dont know how

```py
biggestLength = 0

lengthList = []
after = 1

length = math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)

lengthList.append(length)
biggestLength = lengthList[0]
if len(lengthList) == 30:
    while x < 30:
        if lengthList[after] > biggestLength:
            lengthList[after] = biggestLength
        after += 1
        x += 1
    lastWaste = lengthList.index(biggestLength)
    print (biggestLength)
    lengthList = []
```

Comment: I think this is too broad/vague. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value of a list can be get by [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```py
biggestLength = max(lengthList)
```

Comment: that helped a lot, but the program still resets all objects randomly.

Comment: @adb !? Do you think I can guess your program?